# What methods do you use to optimize the work and performance of the backend part (.php)?

Tags: magento2, php, database, performance, optimization

I want to try to optimize the performance of Magento 2.
After searching this question, I see that for the most part everyone removes modules that are not used on the project or that are obsolete.
But I want to find even more options to improve the performance of the Magento 2 backend (*.php).

Tell me what you use or what I can try in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to improving code by following points.

A. Check code where `Collection` is use, pass proper fields into conditions so you get accurate result.

B. Proper Use of `Collection`, `Interface`, `Repository`.

C. Try to maximum use of magento ready made code.

D. Your development must according to magento standard like `MEQP`